# Editing commit authors on deleted git branch

Tags: git, github, git-filter-repo

There are several commits showing up on a GitHub repo deleted branch under my alt account, and the alt account is now shown as a collaborator, even though I have not added any collaborators, and it still shows that way in the collaborator settings.

This issue arose from making several commits on a repo from an email and username from one of my alt GitHub accounts. The repo is not owned by the alt account, and that alt account has no permissions to edit it. However since git author and git remote authentication are disconnected, it let me push my changes anyways, and I didn't notice that I was still authoring as my alt account.

To solve this, I decided to use git-filter-repo with the --mailmap system, to rewrite the authors of all commits under my alt. This worked great once I figured it out, and checking git log shows all commits under the proper author, my main account.

However, some of the commits were under a branch that I merged and deleted on GitHub. Viewing this branch from GitHub, by going to pull requests > closed branches, there are still several commits attributed to my alt account. And my alt account is also still shown as a contributor.

How could I manage these commits that git-filter-repo didn't seem to catch?